# jQuery click is not bubbling up to parent

Tags: jquery, click, event-bubbling

When `div.arrow` is clicked, its class should toggle and the collapsed content should expand/collapse. This is working, but the click event on `div.arrow` is not bubbling up to it's parent, `li.level1`. On a related note, how would I get the sibling, `span` to also be included in this bubbling?

***HTML***

```
<ul id="list">
    <li class="level1"><div class="arrow arrow-down"></div>Exact Matches
        <ul id="ul_first" class="level1a">
            <li><b>GE</b> Ab Illo Inventore: ASJK: (2365)</li>
            <li><b>GE</b> Doloremque: PEOJ: (92454)</li>
            <li>Eaque <b>GE</b> Ipsa Quae</li>
            <li>Porro Quisquam <b>GE</b> Est</li>
            <li>Sit Voluptatem <b>GE</b></li>
        </ul>
    </li>   
    <li class="level1"><div class="arrow arrow-right"></div>Advisor <span>(7)</span>
        <ul class="level1a">
            <li>Ab Ill<b>ge</b>o Inventore</li>
            <li>A<b>ge</b>usantium</li>
            <li>Aspernatur Aut<b>ge</b></li>
            <li>Beata<b>ge</b>e Vitae Dicta</li>
            <li>Consequuntur<b>ge</b></li>
            <li>Geloremque</li>
            <li>Geque Ipsa Quae</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
```

***CSS***

```
li.level1 .arrow-down, li.level1 .arrow-right {
    width: 0; 
    height: 0; 
    position: absolute;
}

li.level1 .arrow-down {
    border-left: 5px solid transparent;
    border-right: 5px solid transparent;
    border-top: 7px solid #444;
    left: -16px;
    top: 7px;
}

li.level1 .arrow-right {
    border-top: 5px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 5px solid transparent;
    border-left: 7px solid #444;
    left: -12px;
    top: 5px;
}
```

***JS***

```
$('div.arrow').click(function(){
    var arrowRight = $(this).hasClass('arrow-right');  
    var arrowDown = $(this).hasClass('arrow-down');
    console.log("R: "+arrowRight);
    console.log("D: "+arrowDown);

    $(this).parent().children('ul.level1a').slideToggle();

    if (arrowRight) {
        $(this).removeClass('arrow-right').addClass('arrow-down');
    } else if (arrowDown) {
        $(this).removeClass('arrow-down').addClass('arrow-right');
    };  
});
```

Comment: To bubble the event to li you would need to bind click to li instead of div.arrow

Answer (score 1):

Check demo here, http://jsfiddle.net/LFp5n/

Use `$(this).parent().children('span.sibling')` to select siblings

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: `$(this).parent().children('span.sibling')` is the only part I added to make the given question work, rest was already done in question. Thanks for suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can shorten your code to this:

```
$('#list > li').click(function () {
    $(this).find('ul.level1a').slideToggle();
    $(this).find('.arrow').toggleClass('arrow-right arrow-down');
});
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2CQLj/1/)**

Comment: I appreciate the code shortening. I couldn't get toggleClass to work. However, the arrows (or span) still aren't triggering the click event.